# react dynamic key on mapping object

Tags: reactjs, key

I need to get an object inside a mapping by dynamic key, it works with string but not with dynamic name on mapping...

dynamic object

```
data.map((item) => (

        console.log("** works with string:", props.programStructure["induction"]),

        console.log("** not working with dynamic:", props.programStructure[item.name])
    ))
```

Comment: `props.programStructure[item.name]` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Blockquote
> console.log("** not working with dynamic:", props.programStructure[[item.name]])

I think it is because of the extra `[]` in `props.programStructure[[item.name]]`

removed the extra `[]`

```js
var props  = {
  programStructure: {a: 1, b:2, induction: 'intro value'}
}

var data = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}]


data.map((item) => (

        console.log("** works with string:", props.programStructure["induction"]),

        console.log("** not working with dynamic:", props.programStructure[item.name])
    ))
```

Comment: thanks, remoed the []. but not working yet...

Comment: can you post an example `data` what you are iterating ?